# ValueError for trying to convert a string with a decimal point into a float in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python 3 programme here that's supposed to take four numbers and cross-multiply them; after this it's supposed to take answers, divide them and return the square root. However, I have a little problem, Here's the full programme:

```
# !/usr/bin/python 3.5.2
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import math



def data_prosesering():

    ratio = list(input('ratio numbers: ').replace(' ', ''))  

    r1 = float(ratio[0]) * float(ratio[1])
    r2 = float(ratio[2]) * float(ratio[3])

    a = r1/r2

    print(math.sqrt(a))

data_prosesering()
```

Input example (separated by spaces):
`ratio numbers: 5 6 7 8`
whenever I try to use numbers with decimal points (eg. 5.6) i get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 27, in <module>
  data_prosesering()
File "/path/to/file.py", line 19, in data_prosesering
   r1 = float(ratio[0]) * float(ratio[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

EDIT:

I have run this programme in [Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) (an online editor). The first time, it worked fine (at least for integers), but the second time, it kept printing out the user input after I gave it the numbers and pressed enter:

```
ratio numbers:
```

I have also tried using the solutions of @pankaj-singhal and @john-gordon with an addition I got from another answer (also enclosing the code inside the function inside a try...except block):

```
ratio = (input('ratio numbers: '))  
ratio.replace(' ', '')
ratio.split()
```

Unfortunately I could not see the results because of the problem mentioned above, I will select an answer as soon as a solution could be found to this issue (either by me or someone else).

If anyone has an answer to this problem it would be greatly appreciated :). Again, here's the complete code of the project:

```
# !/usr/bin/python 3.5.2
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import math



def data_prosesering():
    try:
        ratio = (input('ratio numbers: '))  
        ratio.replace(' ', '')
        ratio.split()

        r1 = float(ratio[0]) * float(ratio[1])
        r2 = float(ratio[2]) * float(ratio[3])

        a = r1/r2

        print(math.sqrt(a))
        
    except Exception:
        print("An error has occured")
        
data_prosesering()
```

Thanks to Pankaj Singhal and John Gordon for your contributions!

Operating system: Linux Mint Cinnamon,
IDE: IDLE

Comment: You should include what you are inputting to the script -- please copy/paste what all the input/output looks like in the console when this error happens.

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  `list(a_string)` gives a list of single characters.  `float('.')` gives your error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a input with space separated numbers, you can split them in parts with `split`:

```
ratio = input('ratio numbers: ').split()

r1 = float(ratio[0]) * float(ratio[1])
r2 = float(ratio[2]) * float(ratio[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

`list(input(...))` makes a list of *each individual character* in the input, which is probably not what you wanted.

Try this instead:

```
ratio = input('ratio numbers: ').split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python's [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function which splits, by default, on all whitespace characters and will give you `list` of numbers.

```
ratio = input('ratio numbers: ').split()
```

Then, your `float` conversion & multiplication would work.

Comment: I meant that only. Maybe I should explicitly mention that in the answer.